# google spreadsheet sumif function gives wrong sum for spanned rows

Tags: sum, google-sheets, excel-formula

Here is a sample of [google spredsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/prasannaeagle.com/spreadsheets/d/15FndkwslK0dPWWrxBnww7RxBZ7suyPOuvlc7hk67gEg/edit#gid=0) where `=sumif(A1:A5, "Ram", B1:B5)` give correct sum whereas if I merge the rows the sum become incorrect. Why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, sheets reads the merged cell as 1 cell, and so only applies it to one reference cell.

I don't really understand why you would choose to use a merged cell in this instance any way, when there's already a perfectly good answer there.

Comment: I tried the same formula in excel 2007, and it gave 1 as the result again.